# Clear POSTDATA in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to clear POSTDATA (or HTTP POST) by asp.net after page get Submitted?

Comment: Can you be a little more clear about what property or object you are referring to by "POSTDATA" ?

Comment: @DuckMaestro : html POSTDATA (or i am wrong and HTTP POST is right )when submit a form. i sent data and clear form. but  if page get refreshed (not postbacked) data will sent again.

Comment: Please always spend some time to make questions clear, so that we can understand and help. Please update your question.

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar : Sorry Bro.. :|

Comment: Why you want to do such a dirty thing? I think there is sure a better way. Tell us what you want to do, and why you want to clear this stuff. There is absolutly no reason to clear the postdata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways is to redirect to a page (possibly to the same page) after the data is submitted (HTTP POST performed). This however will lose the context and information from the initial POST. Depending on your needs, this might not be a problem. Or else, some tweaking might help, .e.g Redirect to the same page with some QueryString data.

Comment: **Redirect to the same page with some QueryString data** => that's my main problem. when i Redirect to same page by Redirect( Request.Url.AbsolutePath ) I lost my querystrings. is it wrong?

Comment: @Raika, `AbsolutePath` does not include scheme, hostname and querystring. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absolutepath.aspx You can try `PathAndQuery`, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dswc84c.aspx